# SSH tunnel vs Port Forwarding to local VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a dummy virtualbox VM guest where I'm running a python web server just to learn about networking

```
> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 4566
```

Now I want to connect to it from my host

I'm trying to understand why if I do an ssh tunnel like

```
> ssh -L 4566:127.0.0.1:4566 root@localhost
```

and then from the host I run `curl -v http://localhost:4566` I get a proper response (makes sense to me) but if I kill the tunnel and then configure Port Forwarding in virtualbox to forward port 4566 in the host to port 4566 in the guest and try to curl from the host now I can't establish a connection

How is port forwarding different than an ssh tunnel in this scenario?

I thought it was because my webserver was bound to address 127.0.0.1 but it is actually bound to 0.0.0.0

```
> netstat -ln | grep 4566
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4566            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: How is the networking in virtualbox is set up?

Comment: only 1 adapter using NAT

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have expected the given ssh-tunnel and curl to actually connect to the server in the VM.

Maybe you accidentally had the SimpleHTTPServer running on host, rather than (or additionally to) on the VM?

Comment: It's just a hypothesis, but you can test it by running the curl without the ssh tunnel, or testing with and without the tunnel in quick succession without changing anything else at that time.